# General formula for collisions involving rotation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, collision

I am trying to write a 2d game engine involving collisions of convex polygons. Using the basic formula for [elastic collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision) I am able make my shapes collide realistically only considering their linear motion.

$${\displaystyle {\begin{array}{ccc}v_{1}&=&{\dfrac {m_{1}-m_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}}u_{1}+{\dfrac {2m_{2}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}}u_{2}\\[.5em]v_{2}&=&{\dfrac {2m_{1}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}}u_{1}+{\dfrac {m_{2}-m_{1}}{m_{1}+m_{2}}}u_{2}\end{array}}}$$

Since my polygons are not round and sometimes hit each other at angles, they should also gain some rotational momentum after the collision. I am able to calculate mass, rotational inertia and centroid from the polygon. What I do not have is a nice general formula for collisions involving rotations. It should take the point of impact and the previous angular impulses/momenta as input and output the new angular momenta/velocities. Please let me know, if you have any idea what could help my problem or where I could read up on this topic.

[image]

Comment: Seems to me that the first thing you need to do is detect where they interact. In general, this seems like it would be a point on each polygon. For the example you showed, however, it is a line contact for each. I would first determine the location of this point relative to the centroid. Then, you need to make an assumption about the impacting force. If there is no friction, it is common to assume it acts normal to the contacting surface of each polygon. However, you could have point contacts. So you want to define a normal for your polygon corners using the neighboring edges...

Comment: From there, you have a model for the interaction force and you should be able to use the coefficient of restitution definition to relate the angular velocities before to after the collision. That and conservation of angular momentum of the system should give you two equations for two unknowns: the post-collision angular velocities.

Comment: Hi @Evan thanks for your responce. My code already calculates the point of impact and normal vector. However, I'm still not 100% sure on how to apply the conservation of angular momentum. What I had read up online only covered pure rotational cases. Since my objects do not rotate before impact I cannot use the previous rotational energy since there isn't any. Do I have to model both polygons as point masses and then use r*p=I*ω? Also, does 100% of the impact momentum get converted into rotational energy or does it rely on rotational inertia?

Comment: We might want to start a chat because I can see a back and forth happening here… The first thing to clarify is that angular momentum of the system is conserved through the impact, but you need to be careful: angular momentum about which point? Translating bodies have angular momentum about a point that is not their center of mass/centroid. For example, the angular momentum about a point on the contacting line in your example is initially counter clockwise/out of the page. Are you assuming elastic frictionless collisions? Then the total energy is also conserved through the impact…

Comment: but each polygon contributes to the total energy and each polygon’s energy in turn can be split into a translational piece and rotational piece.

Comment: @Evan I think that was the point I didn't understand. I wasn't aware that the two bodies form a system with a combined angular momentum around a single point. I should be able to calculate the rest from now on. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Great, one last clarifying item: the angular momentum of the system is conserved about *any* point. The angular momentum of each polygon individually is *also* conserved, but only about the *contacting* point (the point where the collision forces pass through). Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assume two bodies with masses $m_i$, CoMs $\mathbf r_i$ at the collision time, moments of inertia $I_i$, velocities $\mathbf v_i$, angular velocities $\omega_i$ have impact at point $\mathbf q$ and the normal $\mathbf n$. You can ask the question, what is the momentum $\mathbf p = p\mathbf n$ transferred from one body to another, so the energy is conserved?

$$
\Delta E_i = \frac{(m_i\mathbf v_i + (-1)^ip\mathbf n)^2}{2m_i}+\frac{(I_i\omega_i + (-1)^i(\mathbf q-\mathbf r_i)\times \mathbf n p)^2}{2I_i}-\frac{m_i\mathbf v_i^2}2-\frac{I_i\omega_i^2}2,
$$

where cross product is understood in 2d context: $\mathbf a \times \mathbf b = a_xb_y - a_yb_x$.

Equation $\Delta E_1+\Delta E_2 = 0$ is a quadratic equation on $p$. One root $p=0$ corresponds to the state before the collision, another one is what you are looking for.